# PyWavelets CWT: resampling vs recomputing wavelet

Tags: dft, convolution, wavelet, cwt, pywavelets

[Related](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/70575/50076). The [implementation](https://github.com/PyWavelets/pywt/blob/v1.1.1/pywt/_cwt.py#L37) pre-integrates a wavelet once, and resamples it at each `scale`, finally `diff`erencing to implement below:

$$
C_{a, b} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \sum_k s(k)\left( \int_{-\infty}^{k+1} \overline{\psi \left(\frac{t-b}{a} \right) }dt - \int_{-\infty}^{k} \overline{\psi \left(\frac{t-b}{a} \right) }dt \right)
$$

But it also does [`* sqrt(scale)`](https://github.com/PyWavelets/pywt/blob/v1.1.1/pywt/_cwt.py#L183), whereas above we're clearly *dividing*; what's the deal? And how's it compare to actually recomputing the wavelet at each scale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normalization is indeed by `1 / sqrt(scale)`, and it's an L2-norm; the trick's in the scale wavelet.

I'll use `wavelet='morl'` throughout. Prior to integrating, we can inspect the wavelet [here](https://github.com/PyWavelets/pywt/blob/v1.1.1/pywt/_functions.py#L107); it's returned by `wavelet.wavefun`, which is binary-compiled, but after some guesswork, I found to it to match exactly with

```
scipy.signal.morlet2(1024, 1024 / 16) * sqrt(1024 / 16) * np.pi**(.25)
```

which is, from [source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.5.2/scipy/signal/wavelets.py#L382), using [Wiki's](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Morlet_wavelet#/Definition) notation, $\psi(t) = \psi_{\sigma}(t/a)$, where $a$ is scale, and

$$
\psi_{\sigma}(t) = e^{j\sigma t} e^{-t^2/2} \tag{1} \label{1}
$$

(scale and $\pi^{-1/4}$ cancel). This is what's [integrated](https://github.com/PyWavelets/pywt/blob/v1.1.1/pywt/_functions.py#L29) via `cumsum(psi) * step`, and then [resampled](https://github.com/PyWavelets/pywt/blob/v1.1.1/pywt/_cwt.py#L154) for all `scales`.

---

**Resampled vs. recomputed**

What exactly is this resampling doing in *in terms of Eq 1*? Is it just a higher resolution of the wavelet at the *same scale*, or is it equivalent to *recomputing* Eq 1 at each scale? Conveniently enough, latter, but only approximately, and approximation degrades substantially for small `scale` (-- [code1](https://pastebin.com/aQ0hDK1y)):

[image]

Notice from code1, however, the recomputed wavelet:

```
Ns = len(int_psi_scale)
w = real(morlet2(Ns, Ns / 16) * sqrt(Ns / 16) * np.pi**(.25))  # repeats first blob
w /= scale
```

**The recomputing includes `1 / scale`, which, together with `* sqrt(scale)`, equals `1 / sqrt(scale)`.** Mystery solved.

---

**Your code is wrong, where's `* step`?**

Replaced by `1 / scale`. How?

In MAE code, notice that for `scale=64`, we have `int_psi_scale == int_psi`, which `== cumsum(psi) * step`. For `w_int`, we do `cumsum(w) / scale`. And `1 / scale` is... `== step`. Thus, the pre-integrated wavelet, `psi`, is just `w` at `scale=64` (in `morlet2` code above, `1024 / 16 == 64`, checks out), and `step` happens to be ... conveniently? `== 1 / scale` when integrating.

Then, why is `1 / scale` there? Unclear. Two possibilities in mind: (1) preserving the wavelet's norm at integration; (2) scaling the *wavelet*, independent of integration.

1. If the wavelet was L1 or L2 normalized before integration, *either* will be preserved. This is from chain rule; just replace $f$ with $\psi$, and $k$ with $1/a$:

$$
\int f(k x) dx = \frac{1}{|k|} \int f(x) dx
$$

2. This seems likelier, as the `diff` later is closely equivalent to undoing the integration, defeating the purpose of (1). Why rescale the wavelet? Normalization - see [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/70643/50076).

---

**You cheated earlier; there is no `w /= scale`**

True, the code actually shows `w_int = cumsum(w) / scale`, but the two are exactly the same. It's thus the earlier question of where `1 / scale` "belongs", or "comes from". This is answered [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/70643/50076), and in other part below.

---

**Why `step == 1 / scale` at integration?** (-- for reference, from [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/70576/50076) (in code1, $n$ is `x`)):

[image]

Just a coincidence, or is `step`, along $n_i$, carefully crafted to yield the convenient resampling properties, which in turn demand `step = 1 / scale`? Don't know, might update answer later.